# Run time (number of steps) of loops with conditions

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o

I'm not sure how to determine the run time in terms of input size N, particularly when it gets into loops with certain restrictions. This is what I've attempted. I'm guessing the constants are correct. How does it look?

```
i = 1;                                //1
k = n;                                //1
while (i <= k) {                      //N+1
    while (i <= k && A[i] < 0) {      //i+2   
        i = i + 1;                    //2i
    }
    while (i <= k && A[k] >= 0) {     //i+2
        k = k - 1;                    //2i
    }
    printf("...");                    //1
    i = i + 1;                        //1
    k = k - 1;                        //1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as burning the candle from both ends. `i` and `k` are going to meet in the middle somewhere, but each element in the array is visited exactly once. So the run time is *O(n)*.

The outer `while` loop is just waiting for the process to finish, so doesn't factor into the computation of running time. The first inner `while` loop moves `i` to the right until it gets stuck. The second inner `while` loop moves `k` to the left until it gets stuck.

The lines

```
i = i + 1;
k = k - 1;
```

move `i` and `k` past the points where they got stuck.

The result is that `i` visits some of the array elements, and `k` visits the other array elements, but each element of the array is visited only once.

Comment: Ahh I see it! Are my counts of the steps in each line correct? In the first inner while loop, for example, I see that one of the conditions is A[i] < 0 which I don't think can be true since i starts with 1?